# Customize Wordpress Navigation Bar

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I need some help to custom my site menu. You can take a look to my site first http://f.coupleshops.com/

You can see the navigation bar at the top (the chef, pastries, etc)

All I want just adding some border into it. Top and Bottom border for the navigation bar. 
See the example here http://www.frankiepress.com.au/shop/

Anyone knows how to play with the CSS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add these two line into the class named "header_top_outer" of [this css](http://f.coupleshops.com/wp-content/themes/lamaison1/css/stylesheet.min.css?ver=3.6.1) (I mean the css file named stylesheet.min.css) file on your website:

```
border-bottom:1px #000 solid;
border-top:1px #000 solid;
```

the file path: `wp-content/themes/lamaison1/css/stylesheet.min.css`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have used **wp_nav_menu()** for displaying the menu.
Now in wp_nav_menu() their are different parameters which you can use,
In that 1 parameter is "menu_class" in which you can give class name for the <ul> of your menu.

For e.g:

```
         <?php wp_nav_menu(array("menu_class"=>"navigation"));?>
```

The above function will help you to assign a CSS class to the &ltul>.
Now in your CSS file you just have to write

==========================CSS File======================

.navigation{border-bottom:1px #000 solid; border-top:1px #000 solid;} OR

.navigation a{border-bottom:1px #000 solid; border-top:1px #000 solid;}

Please add other CSS in above class if needed according to your requirement.